# MySQL syntax for Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, parent-child, categories

I need to retrieve data from a **Parent > Child > Child** relationship category setup. And I have no CLUE as to the proper SQL query syntax for that.

Help?

Thanks,
Tomer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to query the database.

They are called breadcrumbs. [There are a lot of plugins you can get for this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=breadcrumbs)